# Can't compile libvirt on new Ubuntu 16 install

Tags: libvirt

Following instructions at top of page: https://libvirt.org/compiling.html

Getting the following errors after running ./configure

Thanks

> checking for LIBNL... yes checking for LIBNL_ROUTE3... no configure:
>   error: Package requirements (libnl-route-3.0) were not met:
>
> No package 'libnl-route-3.0' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables
>   LIBNL_ROUTE3_CFLAGS and LIBNL_ROUTE3_LIBS to avoid the need to call
>   pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.

I then try to install that:

> ubuntu@ubuntu-libvirt:~/libvirt-3.5.0$ sudo apt-get install libnl-route-3.0 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package
>   libnl-route-3.0 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libnl-route-3.0'
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libnl-route-3.0'

Then I try this:

> ubuntu@ubuntu-libvirt:~/libvirt-3.5.0$ sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
>
> bnl-3-dev Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done libnl-3-dev is already the newest
>   version (3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
>   remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: I am running exactly the same error, did you manage to install the latest libvirt version on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `sudo apt-get install libnl-route-3-dev`
It will work.

Comment: did not work for me when trying to install `libvirt` on Debian 9.4 using `brew`